# Django post_save get attribute of instance

Tags: python, django

I have a post_save which creates a Product object after a Subscription object is created. I have the instance name populating several fields, I'd like to also pass in an additional attribute. Here is my post_save:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Subscription)
def create_product_subscription(sender, **kwargs):
    subscription = Category.objects.get(name="Subscription")
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        Product.objects.get_or_create(name=kwargs.get('instance'), 
        slug=slugify(kwargs.get('instance')), 
        price=44.98, 
        quantity='3000', 
        publish_date=kwargs.get('instance'), //this is where I'd like to pass an attribute of the instance
        categories=subscription)
```

Here is my Subscription model:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  start_date = models.DateField()
  end_date = models.DateField()
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return unicode(self.start_date)
```

I'd like for the Catalog Publish_Date to pull it's value from the Subscription start_date field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kwargs.get('instance')` will get you the instance of the sender object.

Once we have the instance object, we could perform dot notation lookups on the instance to get attributes.

```
kwargs.get('instance').yourattribute
```

Alternatively, we could use a more declarative function definition and include the instance and created variables as positional arguments as documented here in the Django documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

Here is what the code would look like using a positional argument for instance,

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Subscription)
def create_product_subscription(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    subscription = Category.objects.get(name="Subscription")
    if created:
        Product.objects.get_or_create(name=instance, 
        slug=slugify(instance), 
        price=44.98, 
        quantity='3000', 
        publish_date=instance.start_date, //this is where I'd like to pass an attribute of the instance
        categories=subscription)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was trying to figure out.